# PHP curl to github rest api does not return anything

Tags: php, github, curl

Based on https://docs.github.com/en/rest/commits/commits?apiVersion=2022-11-28 I have this code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/commits");
$headers = [
    'Accept: application/vnd.github+json',
    'Authorization: Bearer <my personal token>',
    'X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28'
];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print $server_output ;
```

But it does not return anything. It's white page. If I access the url in the browser directly I am able to see the response from the API.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You're missing the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option.

Comment: @Barmar does not solve the issue

Comment: What is `OWNER/REPO` in your case? Is it a public repo?

Comment: I've updated the questin with the owner and repo, yes its public

Comment: I've added a complete code snippet in my answer. Doesn't that work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to make it work. Besides the user agent I had set this option:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
```

Without this, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Please read https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.curl-setopt.php#110457 on how to update your CA bundle.

Answer (score 2):

GitHub requires you to send a `User-Agent`:

*Request forbidden by administrative rules.
Please make sure your request has a User-Agent header
(https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api#user-agent-required).*

Apparently PHP's `curl` module does not automatically send one. Setting the `User-Agent` header manually via

```php
$headers = [
  …
  'User-Agent: curl'
];
```

or

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "curl");
```

works for me.

---

Simplified working example:

```php
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/commits");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "curl");
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Isn't that the default user agent when you use the curl library>?

Comment: Does not solve the issue

Comment: It can't work like that. For me it does not print anything and i am trying on my localhost using wamp. Also in their api they ask for the token, how can it work without one ?

Comment: It can: `curl_exec` directly dumps the result. It obviously works without token: `curl -i https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/commits | less`. No WAMP, but PHP 8 on Linux here.

Comment: But I gave you the thumbs up because the user agent was a must also because without it it won't work either. But this did not solved my problem. It worked only if I had both set. I use a wamp server, maybe it was because it was an old version? I dont know. I am happy it works. I found the answer in another stackoverflow post a few minutes ago.